# How do I get the Broadcom STA wireless driver to load in Ubuntu 12.04? This is on an Inspiron 1721

Tags: 12.04, wireless

When I try to activate it a jockey.log is created.  This is the internal wireless that worked in Ubuntu 11.10.  Doesn't now that I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04.  I'm using a USB wi-fi for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect to the internet using eternet cable, the try this command:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

A restart will be required after installation.

Answer (score 0):

12.04 needs a little extra step to make the sta driver install, it needs.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source

sudo modprobe wl
```

at least it did when it came out, it might have been fixed down the line.